# How to turn off partial content response in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, http

I was playing around with apache and a chromecast with video, and as far as I can tell, the local video will only play on the chromecast if it gets a 200 response, rather than a 206 response.

Is it possible to configure apache (or suggest another web server) to respond to

```
range: bytes 0-
```

with

```
200, OK
```

which is what chromecast appears to expect, rather than the partial content

```
206, Partial Content
```

### Edit

This is not a duplicate of [Is there a way of disabled byte-range requests in Apache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/151591/is-there-a-way-of-disabled-byte-range-requests-in-apache).  I want to support partial-content, with the special case that if all the file is requested, then the response is 200 rather than 206.

The result of disabling responses, would give a 200 request as I require in my special case, but disable the ability to do resumable downloads or stream from the stored content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work with nodejs

[code project : HTTP partial content in node-js](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/813480/HTTP-Partial-Content-In-Node-js).  This allowed me to check response headers and results, and the chromecast did not care about the 200/206, but did care about CORS headers ([google : chromecast](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender#cors-requirements)).

Once I had added

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin   "*"
 Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Type"
 Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Accept-Encoding"
 Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Range"
```

to my `<Directory>` then the chromecast started working with standard apache.

### Review of apache code

I also did a review of apache code, and further checks by using a mis-spelled Header (`Rnge` rather than `Range`).  The apache code is hard-wired to return 206, and has no mechanism I could find to override this.